# What do do about PHP sess_ files not being cleaned up due to cron error?

Tags: php, cron, session

I've been getting an error in cron like this:

```
CRON[17744]: (CRON) error (grandchild #17745 failed with exit status 1)
```

in syslogs.  I ignored it for a while (brilliant, I know), and then suddenly my vps had exceeded its inode quota.  Poking around, it turns out that php wasn't deleting session files, which I assume is the cron error I am seeing (some hints at this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654310/cleanup-php-session-files)).  Here's my `/etc/cron.d/php5` entry:

```
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
```

I assume the cron entry is okay, since I can't believe I've edited it... what could be wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this the other day on Ubuntu 11.10. There's an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/876387) - and restoring 11.04's `/etc/cron.d/php5` command worked perfectly.